# How do I fix problems with KERAS

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, model

I want to use the full codes from

https://becominghuman.ai/building-an-image-classifier-using-deep-learning-in-python-totally-from-a-beginners-perspective-be8dbaf22dd8

regarding image identifiers. However there is problem with the KERAS. everytime I run

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
```

it gives this:

```
%run -i "/var/folders/23/fqcfyh1n5992xf4k9w0f40th0000gn/T/tmpP_8Umu.py"
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent 
call last)
/var/folders/23/fqcfyh1n5992xf4k9w0f40th0000gn/T/tmpP_8Umu.py in . 
<module>()
1 from keras.models import Sequential
  2 from keras.layers import Conv2D
  3 from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
  4 from keras.layers import Flatten
  5 from keras.layers import Dense
```

ImportError: No module named 'keras.models'

I tried to re-install KERAS, but it doesn't work

```
sudo pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git --upgrade
```

## this doesn't work

The previous codes seems to re-download and re-install KERAS, but still keras.models and keras.layers cannot be loaded and founded.

Comment: Did you install tensorflow/theno?  Beacuse when i check the git code there is also need an install either one of them. https://github.com/venkateshtata/cnn_medium./blob/master/cnn.py

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old version of Keras, from fchollet's old repository, the modern repository is https://github.com/keras-team/keras/

You should install keras using pip directly without github, like:

```
pip install --user keras
```

This will install the latest version in your use folder. Try to avoid using pip with sudo.

Comment: But it says, the version is satisfied.

Requirement already satisfied: keras in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py2.7.egg (2.2.4)

Comment: @J.Richard You should first remove the keras version you installed with sudo.

Comment: I enter

pip install --user keras from https://github.com/keras-team/keras/

it end up like this..

 Cannot unpack file /private/var/folders/23/fqcfyh1n5992xf4k9w0f40th0000gn/T/pip-unpack-OhOFPr/keras (downloaded from /private/var/folders/23/fqcfyh1n5992xf4k9w0f40th0000gn/T/pip-req-build-WEi6AG, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of /private/var/folders/23/fqcfyh1n5992xf4k9w0f40th0000gn/T/pip-req-build-WEi6AG

Comment: @J.Richard Why are you doing that? just use pip install --user keras, without anything else, after uninstalling the version installed with sudo.